# TypeScript Record type, C++ equivalent

Tags: c++, typescript, types, enums

The following TypeScript passage defines a list of object types and a set of functions which match a string to determine which tag should be assigned to the string.

```
enum m {
  a,
  b,
  c
}

type obj = {
  source: string,
  type: m
}

const n: Record<m, (char: string) => boolean> = {
  [m.a](char: string) => false,
  [m.b](char: string) => false,
  [m.c](char: string) => false,
}
```

I aim to use this code for lexical analysis, and for extra speed, I'd like to use C++, however as I'm very new to it, I'm not sure how to translate this into C++. If possible, I'd like as close a translation as possible, as this helps me understand what the code is doing far easier.

I've tried using the following snippet to achieve the same behaviour, but I'm nowhere near experienced enough to work out anything beyond this.

```
bool fitsM(m type, std::string source) {
  if (type === m::a)
    return false; // do some checks here
  else if (type == m::b)
    return false; // more checks
  else if (type == m::c)
    return false; // yet more checks
  else
    return false;
}
```

Obviously, this will work, however, as mentioned, I'm looking for a method that more closely resembles the typescript approach.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The closest I can think of is a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: so I'd kinda do something like `std::tuple<m, <function that checks the type>>`?

Comment: I would translate that to a `std::map<m, std::function<bool(std::string)>>`. But if speed is the goal and you know the number of entries in the record you would gain from using a `std::array` and iterate intoit using an enum for example.

Comment: (I assume you mean `[m.a]: (char: string) => false` not `[m.a](char: string) => false`) Typically what you're doing here uses a map or table. And indeed, `Record` in TS is just a stand-in for a map, as normal objects have been historically been used for this due to lack of a native map implementation. So, the most natural translation would be some sort of map structure. I'm not good with C++, so I don't know which one fits best but I'd expect there to be multiple map implementations in the standard library and beyond.

Comment: Also note that the map usage is really just [an application of the strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). So you can most likely get more information for looking for examples of strategy pattern in C++.

Comment: @super could you elaborate on your point on iterating into a `std::array` for speed as I'm not entirely certain what you mean

Comment: An enum in c++ can be converted to it's underlying type. If you use an unsigned int as underlying type you can then have a `std::array<std::function<bool(std::string)>, SIZE> arr;` and access an element of the array through `arr[m::a]`. The array is however fixed size at compile time, but if that's what you need it shuld be a bit faster.

Comment: where `SIZE` is the number of elements in `m`?
That makes sense